# OBS CPU Overload at Idle

Tags: amd-graphics, beta, obs-studio

Guys I am still learning Linux. I moved from Windows years back. Recently since Ubuntu 14 I am having issues with my Laptop. The graphics is an issue I believe. Its Radeon HD 7000 on a VAIO with broken screen. So its hooked to a 42" Plasma. I think Its got decent configuration for OBS. However I get very low frame rate first of all and its almost 100% CPU all the time. At idle its more than 90% for all cores. Its eating the CPU like hell. The Fan is behaving like a jet fan as soon as I open OBS. At present the OBS is just running idle. No streaming no Recording. But still I can feel the heat dissipated from the fan vent.

I am not good at Linux, I am still fiddling with it, Please help me. I may possibly need help with my Linux setup as well. Thanks in advance.

I have a hunch that its either my hardware or ill configured Linux /video drivers. Most probably Drivers or setup of my PC. and then may be hardware. I heard the laptop has hybrid graphics. I am not sure though. I have not been able to get into bios since i removed the factory/recovery partition running viao care in UEFI. If anyone could help me with a perfect setup possibly with Linux I would be grateful.

Thanks In advance. Please help me sort it out. Peace...

More information

lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M]
Subsystem: Sony Corporation Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M]

Someone from OBS forum told me I am running the machine in Virtual Mode which I am sure I am not. But the log says that. I will be extremely thankful for the community if I can get help to solve this problem. And may be understand the problem in the first place so that I can learn more about Linux.

Here is my OBS log

https://pastebin.com/K7uW1q7Y

Comment: What is the output of `top -n1`

Comment: with OBS running only https://pastebin.com/iMEsAeJB


With OBS running and streaming https://pastebin.com/9p6S57U3